# How to override items.phtml in module ? (Magento 2)

Tags: layout, phtml, creditmemo

I am trying to override module-sales/view/frontend/templates/email/creditmemo/items.phtml file but no changes appearing.

Is their any way i can override it in my module ?

Thankyou

Comment: Any thoughts appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:-

create a sales_email_order_creditmemo_items.xml

path:-

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/sales_email_order_creditmemo_items.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/layout_generic.xsd">
    <referenceBlock name="items">
        <action method="setTemplate">
<argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module::email/creditmemo/items.phtml</argument>
        </action>
    </referenceBlock>
</layout>
```

Comment: Hello @Himanshu what to write in layout file for overriding block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Creditmemo\Totals" name="creditmemo_totals" template="Magento_Sales::order/totals.phtml" cacheable="false"> phtml file ?

Answer (score 0):

Please go to your theme and create folder `Magento_Sales/templates/email/creditmemo`

then download `items.phtml` file

from /vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/templates/email/creditmemo/

then paste here `Magento_Sales/templates/email/creditmemo` your theme.

**EDIT**
IF you want to override the template in the custom module, create a new layout file at below location :

```
<Vendor>_<Module>/view/frontend/layout/sales_email_order_creditmemo_items.xml


<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="items">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module::items.phtml</argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: Hi, i am using module so i need to override it in module.